# What's the storage solution used by search engines to store indexes to enable efficient querying and scalability?

Tags: indexing, solr, search-engine, google-search

There are lots of articles on how search engines perform indexing, but couldn't find any information on how they store these indexed records in a way that enables fast querying with scalability. Could someone explain the index storing mechanisms used in search engines or point to any article ?

Answer (score 0):

`Solr` is able to achieve fast search responses because, instead of searching the text directly, it searches an index instead. This is like retrieving pages in a book related to a keyword by scanning the index at the back of a book, as opposed to searching every word of every page of the book.

This type of index is called an `inverted index`, because it inverts a `page-centric` data structure (page->words) to a `keyword-centric` data structure (word->pages).

`Inverted index` is a major term in the domain of `Information Retrieval` and `Natural Language Processing`. Take a document, note down all the unique words appearing in that document as well as frequency of the words. Here you are ready with your own inverted index. Solr creates similar inverted index of the documents posted to its core using a defined schema. `Schema` is a blue print which helps Solr in creating invered index of the documents by giving a set of predefined fields in the `schema.xml` file.

Comment: The question is how it stores these indexes at scale. For an example, say we have a query with two key words and each word might be stored in different nodes of a storage solution (just guessing). So how would it achieve this blazingly fast responses when it has to, say combine results of 10 unique words ?